# Can you use a class name in a conditional statement?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom widget that uses a ListTile.  I would like to set the Leading: property to a Checkbox if the Class A is building the widget, but set the Leading property to Null if Class B is building the widget.

Is it possible for the ListTile to know the name of the class that is building it?

Or is there a better way to approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `is` operator or use `obj.runtimeType` to check the type of object.

Refer to this [link](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-runtime-type-of-object) to understand the difference between them.

Here's an example snippet.

```dart
    class CustomListTile{
         var obj;
         CustomListTile(this.obj);
         void isSameClass(){
            //  if(obj.runtimeType == Truck)
            if(obj is Truck){
              print("Building checkbox");
            }else{
              print("returning Null");
            }
         }
     }
        
    class Chopper{
      
      void test(){
        CustomListTile obj = CustomListTile(this);
        obj.isSameClass();
      }
    }
    
    class Truck{
      
      void test(){
        CustomListTile obj = CustomListTile(this);
        obj.isSameClass();
      }
    }
    
    void main(){
        Chopper objChop = Chopper();
        objChop.test();
      
        Truck objTruck = Truck();
        objTruck.test();
    
    }
```

Comment: .runtimeType is meant for debugging, not production, as it will return the shortened name for the type, which your program will be unable to match.

Comment: Good Point, That's why I have left OP to decide between both based on his requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Would passing a boolean like this do the job for you?

```
class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomListTile({Key? key, this.hasLeading = false}) : super(key: key);

  final bool hasLeading;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: hasLeading ? const Icon(Icons.person) : null,
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        CustomListTile(hasLeading: true), // This one has leading
        CustomListTile(), // This one does not
      ],
    );
  }
}
```